# History of multiple-payload launches?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, interplanetary, launch-vehicle, spaceflight-firsts

Another question asks [why Spirit and Opportunity weren't launched together](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36299/195). My gut response was that multiple-payload launches were less common then than they are today, but I don't actually know if that's true.

**What was the first single launch to put two or more independent payloads into Earth orbit?**

**What was the first time, if ever, that a single launcher put two independent spacecraft on trajectories leaving Earth's sphere of influence?**

Not included: multiple-warhead military applications, or [balloons deployed from Mercury spacecraft or Gemini's "rendezvous evaluation pod"](http://rammb.cira.colostate.edu/dev/hillger/sub-satellites.htm); the payloads have to go into different orbits, or at least phased substantially in the same orbit.

Comment: [Related, but not the same (doesn't deal with the historical part).](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/have-there-been-any-probes-launched-that-were-actually-clusters-of-probes) 1978 - [Pioneer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_Venus_Multiprobe) ***is*** pretty old though :). Does it have to separate in Earth orbit? Or be a set of duplicate probes which are redundant to each other?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about that one! I'll at least throw an upvote at it if you make it an answer. I didn't specify where or how they separated, and they were on different trajectories for weeks between separation and Venus arrival.

Comment: I suggest splitting this question in two

Comment: I agree, the answer to "trajectories leaving Earth's sphere of influence" would be totally different than "into Earth orbit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to

> What was the first single launch to put two or more independent payloads into Earth orbit?

**update:** The Washington Post says it's *probably* this one, confirming [@JoeJobs' answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49746/12102) as well.

[image: image of the Thusrday, June 23, 1960 Washington Post article "Piggy-Back Satellites Hailed As Big Space Gain for U.S."]

**above:** image of the Thusrday, June 23, 1960 Washington Post article "Piggy-Back Satellites Hailed As Big Space Gain for U.S." found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20070726215210/http://www.ncst.nrl.navy.mil/HomePage/GRAB/GRAB_Photos.html

> New Space First
>
> The feat of putting up a pair of satellites simultaneously with a single booster was a new space “first” for the United States. This has not been attempted, so far as it is known, by Russia.
>
> > A two-stage, Thor-able-star, an Air Force Rocket, accomplished the feat.
>
> The Transit II-A satellite, the navigation aide and time-measuring sphere, soared into a near-circular orbit that wil carry it over all of the Earth’s land masses — including Russia — except certain Arctic and antarctic points.

---

Original answer, kept for its archival value:

I can't be sure this is the first attempt, but it might be the strangest-looking: GRAB + ELINT. However it was unsuccessful, and in a very big way.

Taken from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27650/12102):

> The item on top is called [GRAB 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Radiation_and_Background) for Galactic Radiation and Background. However that's a cover:

> > Galactic Radiation and Background (GRAB) was the covername for Project Dyno [ELINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELINT) intelligence satellites operated by the U.S. Naval Research Laboratory (NRL) shortly after the Cold War U-2 incident of 1960. The satellites carried two sets of instruments: an unclassified experiment (called Solrad) and a then-classified payload to collect electronic intelligence (ELINT) (called Tattletale). Of five attempted launches, two missions were successful. The program is also known by the later codeword Canes.

> Reading [further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Radiation_and_Background#Incidents):

> > **Incidents**

> > During the second launch attempt, the Thor booster shut down 12 seconds early, and the flight was subsequently terminated by Range safety. As fragments fell on Cuba, **subsequent launches from Cape Canaveral flew a dogleg trajectory** to reach 70 degree inclination.

> I'm not yet sure if this is the origin of doglegging to orbit, so I've asked [Which launch was the first to use a dogleg maneuver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27651/12102)

> [image]

Comment: That thing looks mighty goofy (in a cool way)-- I have to wonder if the spiral was performing something, may ask after I look around a bit and link here.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn search "spiral" and my user name. You could consider adding the antenna tag to your search by including `[antenna]` in your search string, unless of course [someone has thoughtfully deleted the tag from my question(!)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36263/just-how-pointy-does-a-rockets-nose-need-to-be?noredirect=1#comment115418_36263) as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Thor Ablestar launched on 22 June 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Radiation_and_Background#Operational_history)

- SOLRAD 1, a GRAB satellite
- Transit 2A, an early naval navigation satellite

[Apollo 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_9), launched on March 3, 1969 had a Lunar Module and a Command Module

If the Moon is considered into the Earth's sphere of influence then:

[Viking 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_1) mission to Mars, launched August 20, 1975 - had an orbiter and a lander.

if orbiter-lander are not good then:

Mars Cube One (or MarCO) was a Mars flyby mission launched on 5 May 2018 alongside NASA's InSight Mars lander mission. It consisted of two nanospacecraft, MarCO-A and MarCO-B