# Who started conducting multiple-payload launches routinely, and on which vechicle?

Tags: launch-vehicle, payload

I know multiple-payload launches are routine these days, and everyone seems to have their own reignitable kick-stage. But who were the first to start doing that?

This is similar to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/history-of-multiple-payload-launches), but that was answered with the first attempt at a multiple-payload launch, which was a failure. Who was the first to do it routinely as part of their business model? I know the Ariane V was designed specifically for that, but I don't know that it was the first.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it was [Atlas-Agena](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/atlas_agena.htm). Multiple launches had several payloads manifested, and it was a workhorse for the USAF.

Now, I'm not sure if this will satisfy your question, as many of those primary payloads relied on the Agena to operate on-orbit, but I believe the model of "main payload uses Agena as a bus" and "secondary payload separates & continues on" is close enough to your questions stipulation of "designed specifically for [deploying dual payloads]" so I'll leave this answer here for you to decide. :)

Comment: And in some cases three or even four payloads, it would seem. So they did it back in the 60s, and more than once. I didn't think they did that so early. I guess that answers my question!

Comment: Technically, the most common Atlas configuration produced was multiple-payload but not intended to reach orbit...

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  you referring to MIRVs ?